# To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection,

Tags: react-redux

Anyone encountered this issue before? Any suggestion on how to deal with this? I am currently working on REDUX.

A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.
Note that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the properties is shown.

1 source
content.js:1

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. I was able to find where my issue was. Was missing the logout function to pass on another function.